# Inclination angle of a ray in a static spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, orbital-motion

In accordance with [Synge](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1966MNRAS.131..463S) (equation 8) of the ray with respect to the radial direction in a static Schwarzschild spacetime is

$$ \cot \psi = \left(1 - \rho^{-1} \right)^{-1/2} \rho^{-1} \frac{d \rho}{d \theta} $$

I don't understand how to deduce this expression. I understand that we consider the spatial part of the metric (equation 6):

$$ d s^2=4 m^2\left[\left(1-\rho^{-1}\right)^{-1} d \rho^2+\rho^2\left(d \theta^2+\sin ^2 \theta d \phi^2\right)\right] $$

and we take an infinitesimal triangle with vertices that are infinitesimal increments in $\rho$ and $\theta$ but how does the $\left(1 - \rho^{-1} \right)^{-1/2} \rho^{-1}$ coefficient arise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inclination in a flat 3-space with metric
$$ d s^2=4 m^2\left[d \rho^2+\rho^2\left(d \theta^2+\sin ^2 \theta d \phi^2\right)\right] $$
will be proportional to the coefficient of $d\rho$ divided with the coefficient of $d\theta$, i.e.,

i.e.
$$ {\rm cot}  \,\psi = 1/\rho \frac{d \rho}{d \theta} \,.$$

However, since you are using the 3-metric of a Schwarzschild spacetime  i.e.,
$$ d s^2=4 m^2\left[\left(1-\rho^{-1}\right)^{-1} d \rho^2+\rho^2\left(d \theta^2+\sin ^2 \theta d \phi^2\right)\right] $$

So this gives you what you have, i.e.,
$$ \cot \psi = \left(1 - \rho^{-1} \right)^{-1/2} \rho^{-1} \frac{d \rho}{d \theta} $$

Comment: Why the exponent $1/2$ due to? Is it some kind of normalization?

Comment: That is me just taking square root as the metric is $ds^2$. You need to do that for all coefficients.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Thank you very much for the clarification